# Is there a way consistently find matches with good connection?

Tags: war-thunder

Is there any way in War Thunder's matchmaking to enable parameters for region or ping limit? I'm tired of playing Realistic Battles with 150+ ping against Russians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. While there is only one overarching server for all of War Thunder, there are 4 regional servers for specific areas.

From the [War Thunder FAQ page:](http://warthunder.com/gb/game/faq)

> *Can players from around the world play on any of the US, European, Russian or Asian servers?*
>
> We have one global account server. Users within the game can choose to play on any or all of our EU, US, SEA or RU clusters, so the players can communicate with the world as well as in their native languages.

Before entering matchmaking, click the drop down menu at the top of the screen just above the *To Battle!* button. This will bring up a screen looking like this:

[image: Battle Options]

At the bottom of this new window, there is text stating *"Select Servers:"* followed by the abbreviations of each regional server you currently have selected - in the above case, EU and RU. Simply click this text, and proceed to choose whichever servers you wish to have matchmaking include in its searching.

While this doesn't necessarily pick out the matches with the best connection, using only your region's servers should naturally result in a better average ping.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I wish Gaijin would fix up the MM system so that we could have more variety of play